# The following set of rules are mutually left-recursive

Tags: antlr4

I'm working with ANTLR4 i get the following error:

> The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [primary_expression, primary_no_array_creation_expression].

Below is the snippet from the grammar causing that error:

```
primary_expression
    :   primary_no_array_creation_expression
    |   array_creation_expression
    ;

primary_no_array_creation_expression
    :   literal
    |   simple_name
    |   parenthesized_expression
    |   member_access
    |   primary_expression '.' identifier type_argument_list?
    |   primary_expression '(' argument_list? ')'
    |   primary_no_array_creation_expression '[' argument_list ']'
    |   this_access
    |   base_access
    |   primary_expression '++'
    |   primary_expression '--'
    |   object_creation_expression
    |   delegate_creation_expression
    |   anonymous_object_creation_expression
    |   typeof_expression
    |   checked_expression
    |   unchecked_expression
    |   default_value_expression
    |   anonymous_method_expression
    |   primary_expression '->' identifier
    |   primary_no_array_creation_expression '[' expression ']'
    |   sizeof_expression
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same exact problem and it is discussed here in more details:
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/2.+Example

Answer (score 1):

In your sample grammar, `primary_expression` can be `primary_no_array_creation_expression`.

Then, `primary_no_array_creation_expression` can be `primary_expression ++`.

Therefore, `primary_no_array_creation_expression` can also be `primary_no_array_creation_expression ++`.

This is allowed when there are "one way" dependencies to other rules, for example

```
term   : Digit
       | term Operator term
       ;

product : term Operator term ;
```

would be valid, because even though a term is self-referencing (left-recursive), it is only so in its own definition.

The following would be invalid:

```
term   : Digit
       | term Operator term
       | product Operator product
       ;

product : term Operator term ;
```

Here, a `product` references a `term` and vice versa, therefore creating a mutually left recursive pattern.

You should break your grammar probably up into different rules.